# Flutter/Android SDK with Java 8

Tags: java, android

Setting up my mac for local flutter development. I did all steps as mentioned in the guide, installed Android Studio and also updated the sdks. Here is what my `flutter doctor -v` says:

```
user$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /Users/yeshwanths/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (6 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/yeshwanths/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/yeshwanths/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.3, Build version 10G8
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.6262.58

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
user$
```

So I googled up and found these links:

- [link 1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16025)
- [link 2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16452)
- [link 3](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3139)

Tried all of them but none if them could solve it, when I tried `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I get this error:

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/Users/yeshwanths/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

But I did download the Android Studio and SDK from Android website today only. This is very confusing. Can someone advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem. I tried all possible ways but nothing worked for me. The only solution left is to downgrade java version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify the `android-studio-dir` with `flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android-studio` to configure the path to your android studio, after that run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and you should be able to accept the licenses.